# Keypress CTRL is pressed in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, passwords, keypress

I want to make something like when user press and hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key on keyboard to show him entered password and when he release <kbd>CTRL</kbd> to hide the password on input?

This is what i have for now

```
$(document).keypress(function (event) {

            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if (keycode == '13') {
                $("#password").prop("type", "text");
            }
            else {
                $("#password").prop("type", "password");
            }

        });
```

This is what I made it for ENTER, but i i want to check if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
 is pressed, and when not?

Comment: FYI, at least some versions of IE don't let you change the `type` of an `input` after the first time it's set. For compatibility, you may need to have two inputs and show/hide them (copying the value between).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `ctrlKey` property of the event in `keydown`. It will be `true` if the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key is pressed. You then need to reset the `type` back to `password` on the `keyup` event.

```
$(document).keydown(function (event) {
    $("#password").prop("type", event.ctrlKey ? 'text' : 'password');
}).keyup(function() {
    $("#password").prop("type", 'password');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/4j89wjde/)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes indeed, was just creating a fiddle when I noticed: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/4j89wjde/

Comment: Ok, but i need when CTRL is release to hide password?

Comment: @Gorostas then you need to add a `keyup` handler to reset the type: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/4j89wjde/1/